# Losing final blank lines when assigning command output to a variable

Tags: bash, variables, quoting

*[bash 3.2.57(1) on OSX 10.11.6]*

I am mysteriously losing concluding blank lines in a variable to which I have assigned the output of a command that ends in several blank lines.

```
   [1] $ p="next line is blank

   next several lines are blank


   "
   [2] $ echo $p
   next line is blank next several lines are blank
   [3] $ echo "$p"
   next line is blank

   next several lines are blank



   [4] $ q="$p"
   [5] $ echo "$q"
   next line is blank

   next several lines are blank



   [6] $ r=`echo "$p"`
   [7] $ echo "$r"
   next line is blank

   next several lines are blank
   [8] $
```

Everything that happens in [1] through [6] is as expected.
But [7] is bewildering. Where did the final lines go, and what can I do to keep them when I set `r` to the result of executing a command? (My real command does much more than just echo, but echo is a good minimal example.) Why does this work when I use the value of a variable but not the output of a command?

Comment: added an example on how to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is actually expected behavior.

check here http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Note what it say here

Bash performs the expansion by executing command in a subshell environment and replacing the command substitution with the standard output of the command, **with any trailing newlines deleted**.

to resolve it yu can do this trick (we add one letter at the end of the string so we preserve the lines before it then we remove it)

```
r=`echo "$p"n`
rr=${r::-1}
echo "$rr"
```